# Loop through array, assign new value to variable in array

Tags: arrays, bash

In my script I ask the user for some input and save it into some variables. Before using the strings in the variables I want to cut them if they are too long and add an ellipsis at the end.
So I put all of the variables in an array and send them through a loop and an if statement and reasign the new value to the variable in the array. I have tried many ways and none have worked. The following being an example:

```
preset1="Short string"
preset2="Not long very string"
preset3="A very long string here which we will then cut"

presets=("${preset1}" "${preset2}" "${preset3}")

for x in "${presets[@]}"; do
    if [[ "${#x}" -gt 20 ]]; then
        y="${x:0:20}..."
        presets[$x]="$y"
    fi
done
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop over indexes of your array in order to change the values:

```
for x in "${!presets[@]}"; do
    str=${presets[$x]}
    (( ${#str} > 20 )) && presets[$x]="${str:0:20}..."
done
```

Works for associative and sparse arrays as well.

---

For variety, you can also use **only** parameter expansion like this:

```
for x in "${!presets[@]}"; do
    str=${presets[$x]}
    suffix=${str:20}
    presets[$x]=${str:0:20}${suffix:+...}
done
```

Comment: This and the next solution work, but the variables e.g.: `${preset3}` do not change. Using `bash -x` you can see that the string gets cut and the ellipsis added, but you can see that the value of the variable does not get updated if you do: `echo ${preset3}`.

Comment: @vato And why exactly would you like to do that? Isn't changing the array items enough?

Comment: @vato note that you can also use arrays directly with `read`: `IFS= read -r 'array[0]'`. You don't need variables at all. Just keep the array if it's more convenient for you.

Comment: I will try and explain what it is that I'm trying to achieve. In one part of the script I ask the user for the names of the presets. These presets cannot be too long because I use them in a little menu I print out for the user in a later step of the script.
I could of course use an if statement for every preset and cut the strings there. I just thought, naively, that it might be easier putting everything in an array an use a for loop.

Comment: @vato I understand. But why not use just the array for everything? Why do you want to change even the variables. Creating menus will also be much easier using a list of options in an array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `array[i]` syntax to assign to array elements:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#presets[@]}; ++i)); do
    x=${presets[i]}
    if [[ "${#x}" -gt 20 ]]; then
        y="${x:0:20}..."
        presets[i]="$y"
    fi
done
```